# Automapper - Map one object to another usingdiffrent properties

Tags: automapper

could you help me. I have one object

```
class Source{
 public string A {get;set;}
 public string B {get;set;}
 public string C {get;set;}
 public string D {get;set;}
}
```

And destination object

```
  class Dest{
     public string A1 {get;set;}
     public string B1 {get;set;}

    }
```

Is it possible using Automapper to Create Dest object from source object but first instance of Dest with mapping A to A1 and B to B1, in the second instance of Dest mapping C to A1 and D to B1?

In dreaming solution to get Collection?

Something like:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>{
      cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.A1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.B1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.B;))
      cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.A1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.C))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.B1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.D))});
```

Or:

```
 Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>{
          cfg.CreateMap<Source, ICollection<Dest>>()})
```

[UPDATE]

Maybe better solution will be to use reflection and write custom mapper, with attribute [Attribute(MapType, Order, propertyName)]. E.g

```
class Source{
     [Dest(Dest,1,"A1")]
     public string A {get;set;}
     [Dest(Dest,1,"B1")]
     public string B {get;set;}
     [Dest(Dest,2,"A1")]
     public string C {get;set;}
     [Dest(Dest,2,"B1")]
     public string D {get;set;}
    }
```

New go through properties and create object using type from attributes.

Comment: You can have a condition inside your resolver (MapFrom or ResolveUsing).

Comment: But how can I use it? I still have problem to get Map<source, List<Dest>>.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two mappers:

```
var m1 = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.A1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.B1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.B));
    })
    .CreateMapper();

var m2 = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.A1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.C))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.B1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.D));
    })
    .CreateMapper();
```

And then use them behind another interface (that you define) (e.g. ISourceMapper) which would alternate between the two mappers based on the number of the instance (i.e. instance 1 -> mapper 1, instance 2 -> mapper 2, instance 3 -> mapper 1 ...etc.)

For the collection part, you can then easily call `IEnumerable.Select` passing `ISourceMapper.Map` method to the projection `Func<,>`.